# CSS centered tiles (adjustable width)

Tags: html, css, center

I would like to create a page containing an arbitrary number of tiles of a fixed size where the number of tiles in each row will adjust according to the width of the window. I have created this functionality [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LHDJj/).

However, I want these tiles to be centered within the gray box. I tried creating the intermediary `#tile-box`, which I was thinking I could center and make variable width to match the tiles inside of it, but I couldn't get that to work at all.

Any suggestions on how to get the tiles centered in the gray div?

Comment: `#tile-box { text-align:center; }` - Boom! http://jsfiddle.net/LHDJj/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well i only do this in your code

```
#tile-box {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: table;
    text-align:center; //i only added this line to your css
}
```

you can do this for centering your text, there are many ways that you can present your body in your html, i hope i helped you...

Answer (score 1):

you were most of the the way there but you don't really need `display:table`..

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LHDJj/20/)

**CSS**

```
#body {
    width: 50em;
    max-width: calc(100% - 5em);
    margin: auto;
    padding: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    background-color: #ccc;
    overflow: auto;
}

#tile-box {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    text-align: center;
}

.tile {
    width: 5em;
    height: 5em;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    clear: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I think the `display: table` got left over from one of my previous attempts at fixing this...

Answer (score 0):

Centering horizontal : `text-align: center;`

Centerign vertical : `line-height: 12em;/* Height of the container less the font-size */`

Result online here : http://jsfiddle.net/LHDJj/17/